# How many bits does the longest encoded symbol have, using an Huffman coding on a given probability distribution?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, coding-theory, information-theory

> Having an alphabet made of 1024 symbols, we know that the rarest
>   symbol has a probability of occurrence equal to 10^(-6). Now we want
>   to code all the symbols with Huffman Coding. How many bits will the
>   longest encoded symbol have? How many encoded symbols will have same length?

I try to imagine a Huffman tree for it, but it does not appear to make much sense, as trees for Huffman encoding aren't always balanced (so I can't use tree's height to calculate this I guess). I know that at least two least-probable symbols will have longest codings, but how to relate element's probability with its Huffman code length? Or maybe there is some other way to calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's enough information to answer the question.  Here's a simplified pair of examples, with just 4 symbols $a,b,c,d$:

1. The symbols have probabilities
   $\frac6{34},\frac6{34},\frac{11}{34},\frac{11}{34}$.
   In this case the tree will be $((a b) (c d))$,
   with maximum code length 2 (and 4 symbols having that length).
2. The symbols have probabilities
   $\frac6{34},\frac6{34},\frac9{34},\frac{13}{34}$.
   In this case the tree will be $(((a b) c) d)$, with maximum code length 3 (and 2 symbols having that length).

The minimum probability is the same in these two examples, but the maximum code length is not.  (I imagine a similar example can be cooked up to match your question more exactly.)

Comment: Well, I am quite not convinced by your answer (although thank you very much for answering), I edited my post because I think I might have been quite misunderstood. Could you please check it again? We have: number of all symbols and probability of the least probable (and therefore with longest bit coding) symbol. Is this not enough to calculate the lenght of the longest encoded symbol?

Comment: You clarified "length of coding" to "how many bits [in] longest encoded symbol", right?  Yes, that's what I understood you to mean.  In example 1, the codes are 00,01,10,11; in example 2, they're 000,001,01,1.

Comment: Tough discussion might be comming then. Thank you for your time.